# Another important distinction when considering the effects of migration

Tags: grammar

Could you first have a look at this quote?

> Another important distinction when **considering** the effects of
> migration on children is the type of migration under investigation:
> internal migration (moves within national borders) or international
> migration (moves across national borders).

This quote is from a text given in an English study exercise book published by a Japanese company, as shown in the photo pasted on the link below:
https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/13606566.html

Here is my question: What is the subject of "considering"?

My theory is that the subject of the word "considering" is "Another important distinction." That is, it is "Another important distinction" that considers the effects of migration.

Many others from my country seem to firmly believe that the subject here is "we" or "you" or another human or other humans (not a thing, but a human). That is, according to these people, it is "we, or you, or some human or humans" that consider or considers the effects of migration.

Could you tell me who is correct? Could you also tell me in detail the logical reason for your answer? Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you had the preceding sentence, although I guess that isn't possible with a random sentence in a text book. This would show the context, which is probably about people considering the effects of migration.

Comment: Certainly if you look for similar text the subject becomes obvious given a bit more context. Example, Atlanta Journal Constitution, 2012, via COCA: *Dussling cautioned homeowners repairing cracked driveways that cracks often have a tendency to return. ... Another consideration when planning a driveway or sidewalk repair or replacement is, of course, the neighbors -- - or the city.* Here the entity doing the "planning" is the "homeowners".

Answer (score 3):

The others are correct.  "Considering" means that "the effects" are considered by an entity capable of "considering", that is evaluating according to some criteria, which would be a human or a group of humans.
You may fill in "...when *one is* considering..." to get the correct sense there.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt rely. Yes, I know that an entity capable of "considering" is people. But many verbs expressing some action that seems to be possible by humans alone are used with their subjects being nonhuman, aren't they? What about such phrasing as "This table considers [something]." and "This argument considers..." or "This way of thinking considers..." or "This policy considers..." or "This method (This strategy) considers..." and so on? [To be continued]

Comment: [Continued] In these cases, obviously it is some human who considers all those things, but we often use a rhetorical phrasing by saying "[Some object, thing, or other non-living thing] considers something. I thought that the same rhetoric was being used here.

Comment: The table/the argument/the way of thinking/the method/ the strategy are crystallizations of the considerations of humans. I don't anything in your original example that could fill that role. In fact, distinctions are elements for consideration, ("when considering"), not summaries.

Comment: How about this sentence? [Quote] The first distinction considers the legal character of the text. https://www.google.co.jp/books/edition/Purposive_Interpretation_in_Law/Raze8ZWIO5cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22distinction+considers%22&pg=PA184&printsec=frontcover&bshm=rime/1 -- Please click the link and find the text displayed. The keywords are highlighted in yellow.

Comment: What I mean here is that in all these examples, I believed that the things (such as the table, policy, and strategy) are personified.

Comment: You are right that in other sentences things can consider things, as flowers could consider pollinators friends. You have made your point in your repeated comments. Not here. Whoever is considering the effects of migration on children also needs to make *another important distinction*. The disintiction is not doing the considering.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin -- Thank you for your follow-up. I'm now satisfied with your and Jack O'Flaherty's answers.